# Captcha implementation in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular Js framework.

I need to implement captcha.

[image]

Captcha generates alphanumeric text image. Then we have to enter these texts.

Answer (score 0):

you may try google recaptcha. its a angular directive.
https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha

Comment: Uploaded captcha image. I have to implement this type.

Comment: what is your backend ?